# Relational Data is not fetching

Tags: laravel

My model code is like below.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Listing extends Model
{
    use HasFactory, SoftDeletes;

    public function images(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ListingImage::class, 'id', 'listing_id');
    }

    public function listingItems()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ListingValue::class,'id', 'listing_id');
    }
}
```

I am trying to fetch data like below.

```
$data = Listing::with(['listingItems' => function ($query) {
            $query->select('name as item_name');
        }])->select('*')->get();
        

dd($data);
```

But I am not getting related Data.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As it is relational data, it needs id.

```
$data = Listing::with(['listingItems' => function ($query) {
        $query->select('id', 'name as item_name');
    }])->select('*')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks @Ademir. I used your code. But I am getting result as like before.

Comment: Can you remove array so it is Listing::with('listingItems' =>...)

Comment: Thanks @Ademir. If I remove array it will show error.